# Eclipse Will not run Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been using the Eclipse IDE for some while now, and I go to open it up today and it will not run .java files. For some reason my eclipse is now only configured to run C/C++. Does anyone know how to change this so I can run Java again?

Comment: Change the perspective to Java.

Comment: [This link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/555736/) and [this link](http://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/98966.aspx) suggest that multiple installations of Eclipse are more convenient than switching around workspaces? I haven't tried it myself so I don't know.

Comment: I found that adding an "Open with Eclipse" menu entry to folders outside Eclipse made it very easy to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you downloaded the Eclipse CDT distribution which is packaged for C/C++ development. You should download distributions that support Java such as [Eclipse Jave EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junosr1)  or [Eclipse for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1).

Comment: He'd been using it for a while before this occurred

Answer (score 0):

Try Window -> Open perspective -> Choose one or press other for alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you project perspective is setup for Java